# R rPython remote computer's python

Tags: python, r, raspberry-pi, shiny, rpython

I want to build a [Shiny](http://shiny.rstudio.com/) app and control some hardware through it by using a raspberry pi's GPIO pins.
If I install R on pi itself and use code like

```
library(rPython)
python.exec("
                import RPi.GPIO as GPIO
                import time
                GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BCM)
                GPIO.setwarnings(False)
                GPIO.setup(18,GPIO.OUT)
                GPIO.output(18,GPIO.HIGH)
            ")
```

I can control the output and inputs on GPIO pins pretty well from raspberry pi's R console. But since pi can't host a Shiny server, is there a way I can use my laptop's R session to connect to pi's python environment and control GPIO pins via rPython?
Or any other suggestion for the task?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try R's `svSocket` package. This communicates over TCP/IP protocol. With this package you setup a server on your pi. Like

```
require(svSocket)
startSocketServer(port = 9999) # choose your preferred port
while(1)
{
   ... # some code to do
   Sys.Sleep(0.05) # give the system some time to do other things
}
```

This enables your pi to do some stuff in the `while` statement. And in parallel you can send to it some code which is going to be evaluate from the running server.

In the R session on your computer type:

```
require(svSocket)
con <- socketConnection(port = 9999)

evalServer(con, <code to evaluate on your pi>)
```

This is the way I talk to different R sessions on different computers.

Best!
Martin